# How can i pass a dynamically generated form in angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-grid

Hi i have the following form that is dynamically created. I need to send the form while submitting the form. How can i do it.

Pluker [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/o8PGKSu7GZTvdBY46Wum?p=preview)

```
<form name="MCommForm{{item.Id}}" novalidate="">
    <input type="text" name="MCommentN{{item.Id}}" ng-model="item.Comment">
    <div ng-show="!(MCommForm{{item.Id}}.MCommentN{{item.Id}}.$pristine)" ng-click="grid.appScope.vm.saveComment(MCommForm(item.Id))"></div>
</form>
```

I have tried using MCommForm(item.Id) but its showing undefined ?

Can any one suggest ?

Many Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-submit (ng-submit="submit(MCommForm(item.Id));")
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: Hi, could you provide a plunker or so?

Comment: Hi Victor, 
Here is the plunker requested http://plnkr.co/edit/J9J4czUycQLVqSckDPNO?p=preview

Comment: Hi, you should have a variable in the form object then you can use it like this: ng-submit="saveComment(item.name)" so change the list like this: $scope.list = [{name: 1, value: "1"},{name: "2", value: 2},{name: "3", value: 3}];

Comment: Hi i have tried that too..
But that too is only giving a string only not giving the Object.

Comment: Try do like this if you want the object: ng-submit="submit(MCommForm(item));"